# Why can my HTML element can be identified in Application Modeller but not at runtime? (BluePrism)

Tags: blueprism

I'm pretty new to Blue Prism, and trying to pick up the basics.

Playing around with the Blue Prism resources website (i.e., the introductory blogs), I can successfully spy all `<div>` elements whose class name includes `blog-item` via the regular expression `.*blog\-item[^s].*`, using a dynamic Match Index to parameterise which blog post is used:

[image: Application modeller settings]

My Application Modeller (see below) is able to pick this up when the Match Index is set to 3 or more when I highlight it:

[image: Highlight of element works]

At runtime, I'm able to use a Wait stage to check if the element with the *n'th* Match Index exists (using a Data Item `[Result Index]` which is incremented). Below are the properties for the Wait stage:

[image]

This works where `[Result Index]` equals 1 or 2...

[image]

But as soon as `[Result Index]` increments to 3 or more, the element cannot be found and the Wait stage timeout occurs, despite it being highlighted by the Application Modeller:

[image]

If anyone can allude to a reason why this might be occuring or help me debug why the Dynamic match isn't occuring, that'd be great as I'm stumped on this.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the [Blue Prism community](https://community.blueprism.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=5e3668f0-ad35-42bf-b380-e1c2670abf97&CommunityKey=d8a0860f-1370-4a8d-a272-ad61dbc9b3f3&tab=digestviewer#bm5e3668f0-ad35-42bf-b380-e1c2670abf97):

> This is a bug introduced in version 6.7.
>
> I have reported it and gotten the following reply:
>
> "You can watch out for this fix within the release notes under reference BG-6464. Until then, it is recommended to continue using the workaround of selecting a different set of match attributes."